# TypeError: string indices must be integers on ArangoDB

Tags: python-3.6, arangodb, pyarango

Arango module gives a weird error while accessing databases:

```
from arango import ArangoClient 
client = ArangoClient(hosts='http://localhost:8529/') 
sys_db = client.db('_system', username='root', password='root')
sys_db.databases()
```

below is the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File
>   "/home/ubuntu/arangovenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/arango/database.py",
>   line 699, in databases
>       return self._execute(request, response_handler)   File "/home/ubuntu/arangovenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/arango/api.py",
>   line 66, in _execute
>       return self._executor.execute(request, response_handler)   File "/home/ubuntu/arangovenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/arango/executor.py",
>   line 82, in execute
>       return response_handler(resp)   File "/home/ubuntu/arangovenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/arango/database.py",
>   line 697, in response_handler
>       return resp.body['result'] TypeError: string indices must be integers

calling database module from "packages/arango/database.py" giving me the same error.

my env:

1) ubuntu 16.4

2) python-arango==5.2.1

any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running it on some server, it may be a server issue. It was in my case at least. I ran the following to clear the proxy and it worked fine.

```
export http_proxy=''
```

Answer (score 0):

As I guessed, `resp.body` is not the data type that you provided. `line 697` of `database.py` is expecting something else. For example:

```py
>>> data = "MyName"
>>> print(data[0])
'M'
>>> print(data['anything'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

First `print` command gives the result while seconds command throws the error.

I hope this might solve your problem.

Comment: What is the chane i need to make here

Comment: above mentioned is the code, I am doing nothing other than `sys_db.databases()`

Comment: Most recent call in error message should be the line from your written code only. I can't see any line in error from your own written code. And one more question, what is the name of the source code file that you saved?